# Creating a Hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm creating a hangman game and have come across a problem I can't seem to solve. The following is my code for a correct letter input:

```
            for i, l in enumerate(answer):
                if l == attempt:
                    temp += attempt
                else:
                    temp += hidden[i]
            print(F"Correct! You have {lives} lives left")
            print(temp)
```

which returns: (the answer is duplex)

```
            duplex
            Guess a letter: x
            Correct! You have 5 lives left
            -----x
```

However when a second input is added, it prints a second concatenated string instead of an updated string.

```
            Guess a letter: e
            Correct! You have 5 lives left
            -----x----e-
            Guess a letter:
```

Where am I going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: That is because you are concatenating in both branches of the if statement
`temp += attempt` and `temp += hidden[i]`. You might want to look into some sort of list comprehension

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this code is not reproducible enough to make a [mcve]. What is `attempt`? What is `temp`? What is `hidden`? The first thought is that you are concatenating to temp over and over with `temp +=` each time

Answer (score 0):

Rather than continually appending to the `temp` string, I think you want to replace the specific letters of it as guesses are made.  I'd also suggest giving it a better name than `temp`!

```
visible = ["-"] * len(answer)

# now for each attempt, do:

    if attempt in answer and attempt not in visible:
        print(f"Correct! You have {lives} lives left")

    for i, l in enumerate(answer):
        if l == attempt:
            visible[i] = attempt

    print("".join(visible))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks you very much for taking the time to answer this. I have tried using "visible[i] = attempt" but I receive the following error: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: ah sorry, lemme update that to make it actually work :P  I forget sometimes that strings aren't mutable in Python; the easy fix is to make it a list and then `join` it when it's time to print it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in hidden. in code, you posted isn't added the user input to this array. So hidden is never changed. Try `hidden[i]=attempt` in correct attempt scope. It should look like this.

```
   for i, l in enumerate(answer):
                if l == attempt:
                    temp += attempt
                    hidden[i]=attempt
                else:
                    temp += hidden[i]
            print(F"Correct! You have {lives} lives left")
            print(temp)
```

In python, string has function find, which returns an index of a substring in a string. It could make your code cleaner.

```
index = answer.find(attempt,0)
if(index>0):
   hidden[index] = attempt
print(hidden)
```